# C# RDLC Report Printing

Tags: c#, rdlc

I am working on creating windows forms based business solution. I now need to print an RDLC report directly without opening it in the ReportViewer Control.

Is there any simple way to do it ?

Comment: You can generate a report through the report viewer object directly to a PDF output without ever actually SHOWING the report... Is that what you might be looking for?

Comment: MSDN has a walkthrough [Walkthrough: Printing a Local Report without Preview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx). Essentially, you render each report page on a print page

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The same thing works for SSRS reports as well.